# How to ignore / catch an IllegalArgumentException "No enum constant" while mapping a response using ObjectMapper?

Tags: java, json, exception, org.json

Let's say that I have an enum:

```
public enum SomeType {
    TYPE1, TYPE2, TYPE3
}
```

And I am mapping an API response to a service returning `SomeType` and additional data to it to a `Map<SomeType, SomeTypeDetails>`:

```
private Map<SomeType, SomeTypeDetails> mapSomeTypeResponseJson(String someTypeResponseJSON) {
    JSONObject someTypeResponse = new JSONObject(someTypeResponseJSON);

    return someTypeResponse.toMap().entrySet()
            .stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                    Map.Entry::getKey, someTypeMap ->
                            myObjectMapper.getObjectMapper()
                                    .convertValue(someTypeMap.getValue(), SomeTypeDetails.class))
            );
}
```

But I have no control over the response, and the other team may add some new values to their `SomeType` enum, for example, `TYPE4` and `TYPE5`, and I don't get information about this addition soon enough.

Is there a possibility to make the above `mapSomeTypeResponseJson` method, the part where I work on the response's `entrySet()` ignore unknown `SomeType` values, or - even better - to do it in such a manner that I can catch the `IllegalArgumentException` and `LOGGER.warn()` it, or even do some more complex error processing?

Comment: It’s cleaner and more usual to coordinate releases so that your service is upgraded as required to accept new values. The other option is to delete the enum and use String instead to allow anything, which is your stated intention.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this to ignore the types you don't have configured:

```
private Map<SomeType, SomeTypeDetails> mapSomeTypeResponseJson(String someTypeResponseJSON) {
JSONObject someTypeResponse = new JSONObject(someTypeResponseJSON);

final Set<SomeType> types = Set.of("TYPE1","TYPE2","TYPE3");

return someTypeResponse.toMap().entrySet()
        .stream()
        .peek(entry -> {
                if (!types.contains(entry.getKey())) {
                    System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " is not registered yet.");
                }
            })
        .filter(es -> types.contains(es.getKey()))
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                Map.Entry::getKey, someTypeMap ->
                        myObjectMapper.getObjectMapper()
                                .convertValue(someTypeMap.getValue(), SomeTypeDetails.class))
        );
}
```